# Number in english words using switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

:) I have this exercise where I must convert a number < 1000 into english words. I am trying to use switches, but it fails to return hundreds + decades + singles, so it only works for numbers between 10 and twenty. Here is my code, I checked it in an online lint checker and didn't find any syntax errors.

```
function check() {
var theinput = document.getElementById("theinput");
var answer = document.getElementById("answer");
var number = parseInt(theinput.value);
var singles = number % 10;
var decades = (number / 10) % 10;
var hundreds = (number / 100) % 10;
var text = "The english word for the given number is: ";

if (isNaN(number)) {
    result = "Invalid Integer!";
}
    else {
        if (number > 999) {

            result = "Please enter a maximum 3 digit number!"
        }
            else {
                if (10 < number < 20) {
                    var teens = number;
                    switch (teens) {

                        case 11: result = text + "Eleven"; break;
                        case 12: result = text + "Twelve"; break;
                        case 13: result = text + "Thrirteen"; break;
                        case 14: result = text + "Fourteen"; break;
                        case 15: result = text + "Fifteen"; break;
                        case 16: result = text + "Sixteen"; break;
                        case 17: result = text + "Seventeen"; break;
                        case 18: result = text + "Eighteen"; break;
                        case 19: result = text + "Nineteen"; break;   

                   }
                }
                    else {
                        switch (singles) {

                            case 1: singles = "One"; break;
                            case 2: singles = "Two"; break;
                            case 3: singles = "Three"; break;
                            case 4: singles = "Four"; break;
                            case 5: singles = "Five"; break;
                            case 6: singles = "Six"; break;
                            case 7: singles = "Seven"; break;
                            case 8: singles = "Eight"; break;
                            case 9: singles = "Nine"; break;
                            default: singles = " ";

                        }
                        switch (decades) {

                            case 2: decades = "Twenty"; break;
                            case 3: decades = "Thrirty"; break;
                            case 4: decades = "Fourty"; break;
                            case 5: decades = "Fifty"; break;
                            case 6: decades = "Sixty"; break;
                            case 7: decades = "Seventy"; break;
                            case 8: decades = "Eightty"; break;
                            case 9: decades = "Ninety"; break;
                            default: decades = " ";  

                        }
                        switch (hundreds) {

                            case 1: hundreds = "One hundred and "; break;
                            case 2: hundreds = "Two hundred and "; break;
                            case 3: hundreds = "Three hundred and "; break;
                            case 4: hundreds = "Four hundred and "; break;
                            case 5: hundreds = "Five hundred and "; break;
                            case 6: hundreds = "Six hundred and "; break;
                            case 7: hundreds = "Seven hundred and "; break;
                            case 8: hundreds = "Eight hundred and "; break;
                            case 9: hundreds = "Nine hundred and "; break;
                            default: hundreds = "";
                        }

                        result = text + hundreds + decades + singles;
                    }
            }
    }

    answer.innerHTML = result;        
}
```

Comment: To start with, `10 < number < 20` does not mean what you think it means. Write `10 < number && number < 20`. What happens in your case, `10 < number` will be either `true` or `false`; and both `true` and `false` are less than `20`, so the whole condition is always `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for between 10 and 20

```
if (10 < number < 20) {
```

is wrong

try

```
if (number > 10 && number < 20) {
```

Comment: Thank you! But maybe there is a problem with the switches for hundreds singles and decades or the variables for them. It returns only the singles now :(

Comment: What you need is some debugging then. Either use a IDE or insert some print statements

Comment: Try: 

var decades = parseInt(number / 10);